# Fluent nHibernate no identity column in table

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, identity

How do I specify with fluent NHibernate mapping for a table that doesn't have an identity column?

I want something like this:

```
public sealed class CustomerNewMap : ClassMap<CustomerNew>, IMap
{
    public CustomerNewMap()
    {
        WithTable("customers_NEW");
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Not.Id(); // this is invalid...
        Map(x => x.Username);
        Map(x => x.Company);
    }
}
```

I mean no primary key defined in the database (not much defined in the database).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer to be:

```
  public CustomerNewMap()
  {
        WithTable("customers_NEW");
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Username).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Company);
  }
```

Comment: if i try this all objects with the same key (in your example x.Username) are actually copies of the first that gets retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't directly answer the question.. but it answers the issue in the comment to the accepted answer here.

We had the same issue with a SQL View over our Ledger. The problem is that NHibernate will happily duplicate rows when the `Id` property isn't unique. In our case.. we had Ledger entries that had the `CustomerAccountId` set as the `Id`.. which wasn't unique within the view.
To get around that.. I mapped a CompositeId that was based on whatever I could find that made the row unique. In our case, it was a combination of `CustomerAccountId` and `WeekEnding`:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.CustomerAccountId)
    .KeyProperty(x => x.WeekEnding);
```

This was enough to have NHibernate not map duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to explicitly set a column name in a similar case. Something like

```
  Id(x => x.Username).Column("Username").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
```