# How to Map a VIEW without unique identifing column with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i have readonly VIEWs in an existing Database and i'd like to get them with FHN. i tried mapping it the following way:

```
public class HhstMap : ClassMap<Hhst>
{
    public HhstMap()
    {
        Table("HHST");

        ReadOnly();

        Id();

        Map(x => x.Hkz);
        Map(x => x.Kapitel);
        Map(x => x.Titel);
        Map(x => x.Apl);
        Map(x => x.Hhpz);
    }
}
```

but i got an error:
could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.id as id3_0_, this_.Hkz as Hkz3_0_, this_.Kapitel as Kapitel3_0_, this_.Titel as Titel3_0_, this_.Apl as Apl3_0_, this_.Hhpz as Hhpz3_0_ FROM HHST this_ ]

this is ok cause there is no ID Column, but how can i do mapping with Fluent without the ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could retrieve the records as value objects (non-managed entities) instead of entities.

"14.1.5. Returning non-managed entities
It is possible to apply an `IResultTransformer` to native sql queries. Allowing it to e.g. return non-managed entities.

```
sess.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(CatDTO)))
```

This query specified:
      the SQL query string
      a result transformer

The above query will return a list of `CatDTO` which has been instantiated and injected the values of `NAME` and `BIRTHNAME` into its corresponding properties or fields. "

Comment: should i use compositeid in my mapping with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you: [Fluent nHibernate no identity column in table…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288076/fluent-nhibernate-no-identity-column-in-table)?

EDIT:
Also, you could use a [composite id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920378/fluent-nhibernate-fetching-view-without-unique-identifier), or maybe you need the [latest version](http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/116-mapping-a-view-without-a-unique-id-column) of Fluent Nhibernate?

Comment: it did not work for me. all objects with the same key are actually copies of the first that gets retrieved from the DB

Comment: I added two extra links you might want to try out.